# Unclear apostrophe handling of csh

Tags: csh, apostrophe

Can anybody explain, why

```
#!/bin/csh
tar --file=test.a --append --transform 's,^,data/,'  data/jobid.dat
```

works as expected, creating test.a with data/data/jobid.dat in it,
but

```
#!/bin/csh
set opt="--transform 's,^,data/,'"
echo "$opt"
tar --file=test.a --append "$opt"  data/jobid.dat
```

fails with

```
--transform 's,^,data/,'
tar: unrecognized option '--transform 's,^,data/,''
```

Thanks and cheers,
Matthias

Answer (score 1):

The working case treats `'s,^,data/` as a single argument to the tar program, separate from the `--transform` argument.

This:  `set opt="--transform 's,^,data/,'"` sets the value of opt to the same string.

When you execute `tar … "$opt"` then the value of opt is substituted in as a single command argument, result in an argument which `tar` does not recognize.  The command is not subsequently split into words again -- word-splitting happens before parameter substitution, and is not re-executed for a substitution that occurs within quotes.

I believe (but have not verified) that if you write `$foo` without the quotes, you will get the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks, you gave the crucial hint: "word-splitting". That's way set opt=(--transform 's,^,data/,'), creating a list, helps. No quotes needed then indeed.

Comment: Oh, you know what - I never even noticed before it was a csh question. I answered as if it were bash.  Glad you figured it out.